# How to search file and insert string after match in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, linux

I have the following code in bash:

```
sed \"s/\:root\:/\:root-$(hostname)\:/g\" /etc/passwd
```

That results in:

```
root:x:0:0:root-myhostname.domain.tld:/root:/bin/bash
```

I'm trying to duplicate the same behavior in Ruby.  Can someone please help me?

Comment: Could you post some sample contents of `/etc/passwd`?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `gsub`:

```
longString.gsub(stringToFind,stringToFind+stringToAdd)
```

You can also just run bash in ruby like:

```
`sed \"s/\:root\:/\:root-$(hostname)\:/g\" /etc/passwd`
```

You might also be interested in [this gem](https://github.com/fguillen/SedWrapper).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  Because of the complexity of the regex I have in bash, I'm having trouble getting the right syntax with gsub.  Would you mind showing me how to replicate what I'm doing in bash with ruby gsub?

Comment: I'm not great with that kind of thing but I'll try later today when I have a second.

Comment: If you have some regex, please post what you have.

Comment: The only one I have is the original sed syntax I posted that I'm using in bash.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't.  I'm trying to eliminate running system commands in my code.